# NSDictionary with multiple keys to TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

I´m working on an iOS application that is going to list some data that I stored in a NSDictionary. I will use a table view to do this, but having some problem how I should start.

The data looks something like this:

```
category =     (
            {
        description =             (
                            {
                id = 1;
                name = Apple;
            },
                            {
                id = 5;
                name = Pear;
            },
                            {
                id = 12;
                name = Orange;
            }
        );
        id = 2;
        name = Fruits;
    },
            {
        description =             (
                            {
                id = 4;
                name = Milk;
            },
                            {
                id = 7;
                name = Tea;
            }
        );
        id = 5;
        name = Drinks;
    }
);
```

I´m trying to put all the "category" values as a section in the table and the the "name" from each "description" in the correct section. As I mentioned, not sure how to start here, how do I get a new section for every "category"?

Comment: Above you have an apparent (the "wrapper" is not shown) dictionary entry containing an NSArray of NSDictionaries.  You have to step through the array.

Comment: Even I wonder how to do. If had to do this, i would have created a model class. they its object in array. then it cuold have been easily done.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - It's quite easy.  You access the dictionary containing "category" and extract that element as an NSArray.  Then loop through the NSArray, extracting each array element as an NSDictionary.  That NSDictionary contains elements description, id, and name.  Description, in turn, is an NSArray containing NSDictionarys which each contain an id and a name.  Just peel it like an onion, one layer at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "just have to" implement the table view datasource methods to extract the information
from your dictionary :-)

If `self.dict` is the above dictionary, then `self.dict[@"category"]` is an array containing 
one dictionary per section. Therefore (using the "modern Objective-C subscripting syntax"):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dict[@"category"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.dict[@"category"][section][@"name"];
}
```

For each section,

```
self.dict[@"category"][section][@"description"]
```

is an array containing one dictionary per row. Therefore:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dict[@"category"][section][@"description"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *name = self.dict[@"category"][indexPath.section][@"description"][indexPath.row][@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = name;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Wooow, this must be the answer of the year! Amazing @Martin R, can not thank you enough!

Comment: How would I go about creating a tableview for structure like this?  
`{
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T20:32:01+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533557976799233";
            message = "Message 1";
            picture = "URL";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T13:19:59+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533557810132583";
            message = "Message 2";
        }
    );
`
Some contain a picture element, and some do not.